# Who is whose delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I am a new learner of iOS and I am reading "iOS Programming 4th Edition-Big Nerd Ranch",there is a question while I am reading the 7th chapter.

it says

> A button’s life is relatively simple. For objects with more complex lives, like a text field, Apple uses the delegation pattern. You introduce the text field to one of your objects: “This is your delegate, when anything interesting happens in your life, send a message to him.” The text field keeps a pointer to its delegate. Many of the message it sends to its delegates are informative: “OK, I am done editing!”.

It makes me confused,because at first,it means that the text field can be introduced to one of my objects as a delegate of them,but finally it says " the text field keeps a pointer to its delegate ". Isn't the text field itself a delegate of others,is it? So I don't understand who is whose delegate ? Does it mean that the text field can be delegate of others,but it can also have delegate of itself? or else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That paragraph is poorly written.  The delegate object is (typically) referred to by the UI object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object is the delegate. The text field will be sending the messages to it.

Comment: Got it.because I am a non-native English speaker,so I made some mistakes here.Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have to specify that you want your object to be the delegate of the item and your interface must state it will handle the delegate of your element.  In the case of a UITextField, your interface would be something like MyViewController:  UIVIewController<UITextFieldDelegate>  then in your implementation file you can write MyTextField.delegate = self and lastly implement the delegate methods you want to capture.

Answer (score 0):

Understand what delegate means:  It's *your* delegate -- acting on behalf of your program logic, and interacting with the UI object to tell it what *you* want done.  In a sense *ambassador* would be a better title, since it's representing you in some "remote" location.

Just as there might be a US ambassador to Thailand, your program might have an ambassador to the UITextField object.  When you create the UITextField you tell it what object is it's ambassador/delegate and then the UITextField talks to that object when it needs to know what *you* want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Many of Apple's framework objects take a delegate. A delegate is a pointer to some anonymous object that you know very little about. All you know about it is that it understands a certain set of calls (a protocol). It's like a private lingo.

The idea is that the system object sends information to the delegate to either tell it about what has happened (the user selected the picker item at index 4) or ask it about how it should behave (The user wants to scroll to the left. Should I allow it?)

By using the delegate design pattern, you can build general-purpose objects that can be used in a wide variety of situations, by a wide variety of different objects.

When you read delegate, think "customer". A system object is a shopkeeper. Its delegate is a customer.

The shopkeeper doesn't need to know much about his customer. He takes an order for a product, calls out the customer's number when the order is ready, hands over the product, takes some money, and moves on. The customer doesn't even have to speak very much of the shopkeeper's language - only enough to place the order, understand when the order is ready, and how to pay for it.

The protocol is the language that the object (shopkeeper) uses to talk to it's delegate (customer). It's a limited, formally defined language. Any delegate (customer) who understands the required words in the object's (shopkeeper's) language (protocol) can get services from the object (shopkeeper).

BTW, you should accept the answer that helped you first and/or best, and up-vote all answers that you find useful. In this case I think you should accept @MirekE's answer. He was the first one to give you a clear answer.

Comment: I'm very grateful to you for showing me a great answer and giving me suggestions.I'm very sorry that it's my first time to ask question on stack overflow so that my reputation is not enough for me to vote up any answers,and I will finish it when I get enough reputation.